# Rails - Params Not Being Added to Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here!  I am using s3_direct_upload to upload a basic image to Amazon S3 and then POST to create a record.  I can see in the Network tab (firebug) that it is being POST'd.  However, I'm not sure why the params are not being added to the DB.

This is what I am getting back:

```
   Started POST "/choices" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-02 17:36:10 -0700
   Processing by ChoicesController#create as */*
   Parameters: {"url"=>"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads%2F1380760569802-bneiuk2ghf4-22e59d1c8959be731bc71e31f0a9d7c6%2Fslide0003_image002.jpg",        
   "filepath"=>"/uploads%2F1380760569802-bneiuk2ghf4-22e59d1c8959be731bc71e31f0a9d7c6%2Fslide0003_image002.jpg", 
   "filename"=>"slide0003_image002.jpg", 
   "filesize"=>"73930", 
   "filetype"=>"image/jpeg", 
   "unique_id"=>"bneiuk2ghf4", 
   "choice"=>{
      "image"=>"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads%2F1380760569802-bneiuk2ghf4-22e59d1c8959be731bc71e31f0a9d7c6%2Fslide0003_image002.jpg"
    }
   }
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered choices/create.js.erb (0.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

```
 # app/controllers/choice.rb
  def create
   @choice = Choice.create(choice_params)
  end

 def choice_params
   params.require(:choice).permit!
 end
```

Then my form (some HTML omitted for brevity):

```
#app/views/new.html.erb
   <%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: choices_url, callback_param: "choice[image]", id: "s3-uploader" do %>
      <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
   <% end %>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What you `Choise` model expects on `create`? `require` only returns a `{"image" => "https://..."}` to you. Does your `Choice` model expect this single field? Your model is rolling back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 'ROLLBACK", It looks like you are not saving the record.  Perhaps, some validations are not being met.  Change

```
@choice = Choice.create(choice_params)
```

to

```
@choice = Choice.create!(choice_params)
```

So that you can get back information concerning why your record is not being saved.

Comment: That was it.  Validations were not being met; I forgot to remove an old unnecessary validation.